# Triggering code navigation on gitlab pipeline for a java project

Tags: java, gitlab-ci, code-navigation

I am having trouble enabling the code navigation/intelligence feature by gitlab (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/code_intelligence.html)
The project I am working on is in Java and here is the newly added job for my gitlab-ci.yml :

```
code_navigation:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - runner_tag
  image: sourcegraph/lsif-java:latest
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - lsif-java index -- --batch-mode -DskipTests package
  artifacts:
    reports:
      lsif: dump.lsif
    paths:
      - "dump.lsif"
```

However, it appears that the provided image has java 8 and my project is on version 17.
Thanks.

I tried using scip-java image instead but I don't think gitlab has a keyword to collect the index.scip generated and use it to enable the navigation feature.
Does someone have an idea on how to trigger it ?